# Exponential series proof complex

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove
$$(3-e)|z|\leq |e^z-1| \leq (e-1)|z|$$
$$z\in \bar{D}(0;1)$$

Where do I go from 
$$\left(3-\sum\frac{1}{n!}\right)|z| \leq \left|\sum \frac{z^n}{n!} -1\right| \leq  \left(\sum\frac{1}{n!}-1\right)|z|\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second part is easier :$$\left|e^{z}-1\right|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|z\right|^{n}}{n!}=\left|z\right|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|z\right|^{n-1}}{n!}\leq\left|z\right|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\left|z\right|\left(e-1\right).$$

Try this for the first part :$$\left(3-e\right)\left|z\right|=\left(1-\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\right)\left|z\right|=\left|z\right|-\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|z\right|}{n!}\leq\left|z\right|-\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|z\right|^{n}}{n!}\leq\left|z\right|-\left|\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}\right|\leq\left|z+\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}\right|=\left|e{}^{z}-1\right|.$$
Finally, it is straightforward (and simpler than what I had previously written).

Comment: Edited: I wrote a big mistake, I think it is fixed now! (but check it anyway!!)